# Converting an integer to a 0-padded string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I want to represent an integer as a 3-character string - so:

- 3 becomes `'003'`
- 5 becomes `'005'`
- 107 becomes `'107'`

How can I do this?

Comment: Not only is it considered impolite, but all caps is harder to read.

Comment: People: stop whinging, and *edit* it ;-p

Comment: But Marc, if you don't tell them *why* you've edited it, they're liable to do it again next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT 10
INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT 100

SELECT  REPLICATE('0',3 - LEN(CAST(Val AS VARCHAR(3)))) + CAST(Val AS VARCHAR(3))
FROM    @Table
WHERE   ABS(Val) < 1000
```

Answer (score 7):

```
/* Method 1 Using RIGHT function */
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(NumericColumn AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PaddedCnumericColumn 
FROM MyTable


/* Method 2 Using RIGHT AND REPLICATE function */
SELECT  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 3) + CAST(NumericColumn AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PaddedCnumericColumn 
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: The first approach here is pretty cute.